# how do I start a non-profit?

Tags: participation, volunteers, nonprofit

I'm 14 years old and I want to become a psychologist. I love helping with whatever I can. I volunteer at my local library and volunteer on food drives. I want to inspire and affect people's lives in a good way. I want to help animals and all sorts of people. I really want to start a non-profit focusing on helping animals but I don't know what I need or who I need to talk to, to start it. Can you help me?

Comment: What country are you in?

Answer (score 1):

Hey there and welcome to the Stack Exchange, I love the enthusiasm and the fact you want to help others and do so at a young age. Nothing better to see than the younger generation thrive to help others any way they can, you would be the type of person I would want on my team.

Non-profits are relatively easy to start, considering you're underage you would have to have parental consent at some level because if you're receiving donations you need a bank account, if you're parents dont have an issue with it than my suggestion would to find a charity online that you would be willing to support, back when I started my first YouTube channel at 16 and was partnered (had to have parental consent as well) me and my buddies actually would game for charity and hosts events and all proceeds would go to Doctors Without Borders.

Do research and ask around on google and definitely ask your parents. Cheers and goodluck.